# REST API - Represent resource as primary and sub-resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

In my Rails 4 application I have the following models:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :location_parking_locations
  has_many :parking_locations, through: :location_parking_locations
end

class LocationParkingLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :parking_location
end

class ParkingLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :location_parking_locations
  has_many :locations, through: :location_parking_locations
end
```

A call to the route `/locations/1/parking_locations` returns a collection of parking locations for location = 1. Some of the attributes on the response come from the join model (the `location_parking_location`). For example, one of the parking_locations in the response might look like this:

```
{
  id: 1
  name: 'Test Parking Location'
  description: 'Test description for the parking location'
  upvote_count: 10, <- this field comes from the join model
  downvote_count: 8, <- this field comes from the join model
}
```

If a user would like to update an attribute that comes directly from the parking location, for example, the name, I feel like they should be able to do that through an endpoint that treats the parking location as a primary resource, rather than having to reference it as subresource of a specific location. For example, they should be able to edit or retrieve the parking_location, not specific to a certain location, from the endpoint `/parking_locations/1`.

In this case, the fields that came from the location_parking_location like `upvote_count`, and `downvote_count` should not be included.

Is there some sort of design pattern that will allow for this behavior? Or should I be thinking about this differently? For example, maybe when retrieving the endpoint `locations/1/parking_locations`, I should not be returning a collection of `parking_locations`, but should instead return a collection of `location_parking_locations`, which can include an object representing the attributes from the `parking_location`. In this case, should the endpoint be changed to `locations/1/location_parking_locations`? For example, one of the objects in the response might look like this:

```
{
  id: 9
  upvote_count: 10,
  downvote_count: 8,
  parking_location: {
    id: 1
    name: 'Test Parking Location'
    description: 'Test description for the parking location'
  }
}
```

In that case, how would someone add a new parking location? Would it be done with a post to the `/parking_locations` endpoint? Or should they create it and add it to a location at the same time, maybe by posting to `/locations/1/parking_locations`?

In that case, what if someone wants to add an already existing parking location to a location? In that case maybe they should PUT to `/locations/1/parking_locations/{parking_location_id}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Routes

You can make your `ParkingLocation` model both a primary and subresource with some simple routing and a permissive controller. First, the routing - you'll want to declare it at the top-level in addition to where you already have it as a subresource of `Location`.

```
resources :locations do
  resources :parking_locations
end

resources :parking_locations
```

If you check `rake routes` now, you'll see two sets of URLs that both connect to the `ParkingLocationsController`, one set at `/parking_locations` and one nested at `/locations/:location_id/parking_locations`.

### ParkingLocationsController

Your controller will always receive `params[:id]` containing the ID of the `ParkingLocation`. If you access the nested route, it will also receive `params[:location_id]` containing the ID of the `Location`. Any form submissions, etc. will have `params[:parking_location]` containing the rest of the attributes for create/update/etc. A simple controller might look like this:

```
class ParkingLocationsController
  def index
    if params[:location_id]
      location = Location.find(params[:location_id])
      @parking_locations = location.parking_locations
    else
      @parking_locations = ParkingLocation.all
    end
  end

  def show
    @parking_location = ParkingLocation.find(params[:id])
  end

  # ...
end
```

Note `index` works the same regardless of there the `location_id` parameter comes from:

```
/locations/1/parking_locations
/parking_locations?location_id=1
```

### Adding Locations

Since your RESTful resource is a `ParkingLocation`, you should be handling `Location` additions in `ParkingLocationsController#update`. For simplicity and consistency, your controller shouldn't care whether the route was `PUT /locations/:location_id/parking_locations/:id` or just `PUT /parking_locations/:id`. The `has_many` association provides `ParkingLocation#location_ids=`, which you can collect in a form however you like and pass into the controller. Your `update` action looks the same as always:

```
def update
  @parking_location = ParkingLocation.find(params[:id])
  if @parking_location.update(params[:parking_location])
    redirect_to @parking_location
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

And a request like this will set `Location`s `1` and `2` on `ParkingLocation` `3`:

```
PUT https://your.server/parking_locations/3?parking_location[location_ids[]]=1&parking_location[location_ids[]]=2
```

If you want to append `Location`s, you'll need to do a little more coding to handle that yourself. If you want to create `Location`s inside the `ParkingLocation` form (or vise versa), you'll want to check out Rails' [nested form](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms) features.